# Delete selected row index

Tags: angular

[image: My Forms]

Hello everyone, i have some trouble when delete the row table in Questions table.

**This is my function deleterowtable in component.ts**

```
  deleteQuestions(questionsId: number) {

    this.questionerDetails.removeAt(1);

  }
```

**this is my component html**

```
      <!--qeustion input-->
      <div formArrayName="questionerDetails" class="rap">
        <table id="myTable" align="center" class="table table-bordered">
          <tr><th>Questions</th><th>Actions</th></tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let questions of questionerDetails.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <td><input style="width:100%;" formControlName="questionDetail" class="form-control" placeholder="type your questions here" /></td>
            <td align="center">

              <button (click)="deleteQuestions()" type="button" class="btn btn-success bc"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>

            </td>

          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

My trouble is i just can delete the row table last index or first index. 
Example: i have 5 row table [0],[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RkEh.png),[2],[3],[4], i want delete number [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RkEh.png) the row is deleted and after that i delete number [2]. So the row table have [0],[4].
How to delete the row when i selected the row? 
Thanks.

Comment: are you missing out `i` inside `deleteQuestions()`?

Comment: yeah, that'right, i missing i in deleteQuestions(i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the selected index via your delete method

`(click)="deleteQuestions(i)"`

and this line given the selected index `let i=index`

And your method should be use `splice()` instead of `removeAt()`

```
deleteQuestions(index: number) {
    this.questionerDetails.splice(index, 1);

  }
```

Comment: ok thanks for your answers,but i use removeAt that works,im only missing i in the deleteQuestions()

Comment: @TM Are you sure removeAt is working for you?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501112/uncaught-typeerror-array-removeat-is-not-a-function/50501195#50501195

Comment: yes sure, is that working use removeAt in my code. if i use .splice get error "Property Slice does not exist on type FormArray".

Answer (score 0):

First.
You missed the index in your `deleteQuestion()`. That's why your ts can't find the index of the element you want to delete. You need to change it to `deleteQuestion(i)` which i is your index of element in the table

Second.
The method you should use is `Slice()`, not `removeAt()`.
Here's the docs for it. Have fun
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice