# "Uncaught TypeError: Array.removeAt() is not a function",

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, msdn

I got a [MSDN document for Array.removeAt()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383998.aspx) function.

But when i trying it, I am getting this error : *"Uncaught TypeError: Array.removeAt is not a function",*

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
Array.removeAt(a, 2);
console.log(a);
```

Why it's not working here? And is that is a wrong document?

**Edit:** `a.removeAt(a, 2);` also not working.

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
a.removeAt(a, 2);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: `a.removeAt(a, 2);`?

Comment: @user5173426 That's also not working and getting the same error.

Comment: Yeah, I know how can i do delete. but my question is  that document is correct or not?

Comment: the documentation is an out of date reference to a [tag:JScript] (**not [tag:JavaScript]**) function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `Array.removeAt()` function in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

> MSDN article is an out of date reference to a JScript (not JavaScript)
>   function.

Alternatively you can use `Array.splice()` or some other similar functions.

For more information check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: correct but slightly wrong.  there isn't an "MSDN Library";  the MSDN article is an out of date reference to a JScript (**not JavaScript**) function.

Comment: @Claies Exactly what i thought.

Comment: @Claies thanks for the correction. Updating my answer.

Comment: @RameshRajendran I have updated my answer. Please check it now. I added comment from Claries for more clarity.

Comment: Yeah! I got the point from your answer. And also I have check the array prototype.  **There have no function like remove and removeAt** :+1

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main()
{
    char[] a = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    string str = new string(a);
    int index = str.IndexOf('a');
    str=str.Remove(index,1);
    a = str.ToCharArray();
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

OUTPUT:

> bcde

DEMO:

[dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/umxcLf)

Comment: I am asking this question in javascript. not C# . See that document clearly mentioned that's a jscript code.

Comment: Wait. Whatt! It had a `C#` tag when I saw it! :/

Comment: No way :) ... I clearly mentioned it a javascript and typescript

Comment: `delete a["a"];` does this not work for you in typescript? or `a.splice(2);`

Comment: I know how can i delete it. my question is that document providing wrong details, that's why I am asking here. Any way i got the news for that document is expired :)